# Return to App from Maps

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

When a certain button is pressed inside my application, Apple Maps is opened. Is it possible to start Maps with some kind of back-button included which takes the user back to my app?

My intuition says it cannot be done, is that intuition correct?

Comment: You could use Google Maps for iOS. It has this return to the source app [feature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme#add_navigation_to_your_app).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's true, there is no way back.

You can use [Map Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) in your application, though. See [Displaying Maps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW1) in the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html), simply add a [`MKMapView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) to you App via Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the user interface of another application and the Maps application doesn't provide such "back button" functionality.

You can implement a custom map view if you need only a simple map. If routing and other advanced functionality is used, then you should think over whether it's worth implementing it yourself.